# Why do we need converters for TextFormatters

Tags: java, javafx

My professor said that it is 'ideal' to use a filter and a converter for a TextFormatter. I looked at his examples and tried them, but couldn't understand why we need a converter at all.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html):

> A Formatter describes a format of a TextInputControl text by using two distinct mechanisms:
>
> A filter (getFilter()) that can intercept and modify user input. This helps to keep the text in the desired format. A default text
>   supplier can be used to provide the intial text.
>
> A **value converter** (getValueConverter()) and value (valueProperty()) can be used to provide special format that
>   represents a value of type V. If the control is editable and the text
>   is changed by the user, the value is then updated to correspond to the
>   text.

I am cleary something missing here. I get why you want to convert a string to an integer (for calculations etc.). But why do you have to have it as a part of TextFormatter? Can't we just use getText() and then just cast the text as we want to have the value?

One more thing: If we have a filter that doesn't allow non-numeric characters, then why do we need to take care of the conversion of the text to integer/double etc. with a converter?

Maybe I am just missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a `String` to an `Integer` (or any other type, except an `Object`): you have to convert it. Even if the text formatter has a filter that only allows numeric entry, the text field's `getText()` method still returns a string, which is usually not very convenient (as the entry in the text field likely represents a numeric value in some object).

You might need to get the integer (for example) value represented by the text field in many different places, so you centralize the conversion code in one place by including the converter as part of the formatter.

Additionally, the formatter's value is an observable property, so you can easily bind other properties to it, etc. This would be tricky if you needed to perform the conversion in a binding on the text field's text property.

Comment: But getText() is supposed to return a string, right? You mean it is not convinient to just be able to use getText() and not getValue(). But getValue() isn't set yet, so the converter helps you doing so. Is that correct?

Comment: Calling `getValue()` on the formatted will return the result of passing `getText()` through the converter. So the return type will match the type of the formatter. Post a concrete example if you don't understand.

Comment: Actually, tried it and failed: tf.textProperty().getValue() on a TextField returns me a string not an integer

Comment: I would expect something like that would work: Integer test = tf.textProperty().getValue();

Comment: No, because `textProperty()` is a `StringProperty`. That's the whole point. If your text field represents some type other than a `String`, (an `Integer` in this example) you need to tell it how to convert the string to the other type. That's what the converter is for. So you can now do `Integer test = formatter.getValue()` and it gives you the value processed by the converter.

Comment: I think I got it now, but what I find quite interesting is that Integer test = formatter.getValue() has actually no direct reference to the control. So we are creating a TextFormatter and set it to the control and then just refer the TextFormatter for getValue(). I can even call getValue() without having the TextFormatter being set on a control. I find that a bit weird.

Comment: Umm, no, it won't work unless the text formatter is set on the control. (Or it will just return the default value and not refer to the text.) Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html): *"Since Formatter contains a value which represents the state of the TextInputControl to which it is currently assigned, a single Formatter instance can be used only in one TextInputControl at a time."* I.e. the value of the formatter is determined by the text control *to which is is assigned*.