# Automatic correction of double value input

Tags: filter, javafx-8

I have a field and a filter on it that just allows digits and `,`

I want that if I type `1,` that I automatically have `1,0` when I leave the text field. 
I could parse it and check with a substring whether there is a `,` at the end. But that is not a very good way to do it in my opinion. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are you using a `TextFormatter`? If so, providing a converter should do this for you. (And haven't we already been over this twice before?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a converter in the text formatter you are using to filter the input:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter.Change;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class DecimalTextField extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // decimal formatter for default locale:
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
        decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols() ;
        char decimalSep = symbols.getDecimalSeparator() ;

        UnaryOperator<Change> filter = change -> {
            for (char c : change.getText().toCharArray()) {
                if ( (! Character.isDigit(c)) && c != decimalSep) {
                    return null ;
                }
            }
            return change ;
        };

        StringConverter<Double> converter = new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double object) {
                return object == null ? "" : decimalFormat.format(object);
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string) {
                try {
                    return string.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : decimalFormat.parse(string).doubleValue();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    return 0.0 ;
                }
            }

        };

        TextFormatter<Double> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(converter, 0.0, filter);
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);

        VBox root = new VBox(10, textField, new TextArea());
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(Obviously the filter could be improved here to, e.g. avoid multiple decimal separator characters in the input.)

Comment: why do i have to override the toString and fromString methods?

Comment: How else would the converter know how to convert? I don't really understand that question.

Comment: Sorry, I just never saw someone overriding these methods. I always used these methods without overriding for integers e.g.

Comment: Huh? [You have seen converters before.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245741/why-do-we-need-converters-for-textformatters) It's impossible to write a converter without overriding those methods.

Comment: Oh sorry, I only used given converters actually. Like `new LocalDateStringConverter()`

Comment: Does this solution consider that I want to have `,` for the numbers?

Comment: Ah, it need to use the decimal format to parse the string... see updated version

Comment: When I write `1,` with this, I will have `1`as a result. But I want to have `1,0`in my field :(

Comment: Really? I tried that and (with the locale set to German) I get `1,0`. You have the `setMinimumFractionDigits(1)` call?

Comment: Ah sorry, now it works. Just one little problem more. My filter just allows digits and `,`. If I write lets say 100000,5 i will get 100.000,5 as a result. So i cannot edit it since my filter always thinks it is forbidden because of the `.`. How can I get rid of the `.` ?

Comment: Just fix the decimal formatter to be as you need it. If you want someone to actually do your entire job for you, you need to pay them.

Comment: I just don't know what couses this. Can you give me a hint what I have to look at?

Comment: Are you bothering to understand the code I offer you, say by reading the actual documentation for the method calls, or are you just blindly copying it without even trying to figure out how it works? If you can't be bothered to even read the docs for the classes and methods, I am done here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106653/discussion-between-dennis-von-eich-and-james-d).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best would be to convert the string to a double and then convert the double back to a string using [DecimalFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12806303/360051). That way you know you'll know the number is in your desired format.